# Order array of strings alphabetically with numbers (as string)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I sorted the value of following array with `orderBy: toString()`.

Array: `["Susan","1","121","Adam","11"]`

Unfortunately, the output is:

```
Adam
Susan
11
121
1
```

I'd like to have it like this:

```
1
11
121
Adam
Susan
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="flexitem-0 flexcnt ll-subattribute" ng-repeat="sub_value in item.sub_values track by $index | orderBy:'toString()'">
    <div class="flexspace-l"></div>
    <div class="flexitem-1 flexwrap">{{sub_value}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my fiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/dhruv1992/HB7LU/28312/
```

Worked with your code

Comment: Strange. Could it have to do with the angularjs version? Mine is v1.3.15, I actually don't know the latest.

Comment: It's something with your object